# What kind of datatype is 32.99 in SQL?

Tags: sql, database, pgadmin

I'm trying to create tables for a database for an assignment i've been given. I'm not the most experienced with SQL, but things were going well until the products table. I don't know how to use the last one, the prices. Most of these end on .99 (example: 239.99) and nobody ever really explained this well to me.

I'm using pgadmin4 for this, as it's the application i've been taught some very basic SQL things in. I'm just needing to create the tables and then add the data csv files to it, we've already got an ERD diagram. I really don't know how to define this prices data though. Anyone know? Any help and thinking along is most appreciated and valued!

Short edit: i'm aware this is a numerical type, but i don't know which sort and numerical i don't think is specific enough for this kind of thing really.

```
( product_id bigserial, product_name text, brand_id bigserial, 
category_id bigserial, model_year bigserial, list_price [datatype but IDK what to use] );
```

Comment: The data type would be *decimal or numeric* with the appropriate precision and scale.

Comment: Would you please explain precision and scale here? I've never been told about those before. Is scale the max size of the things in this list?

Again sorry if i sound stupid, i've only been taught the very basics and my teacher was honestly unfit to teach us this. I don't think he knew what he was talking about half of the time.

Comment: You could type 'pricision and scale' into a google search, there are a few results. [http://sqlrelay.sourceforge.net/sqlrelay/programming/precisionscale.html](http://sqlrelay.sourceforge.net/sqlrelay/programming/precisionscale.html)

Comment: Thank you, i think that's clear enough to me then. Thanks again!

Comment: I may be wrong but I expect the answer may be different for different SQL implementations. I use SQLite which seems to be less exacting than others in terms of data types. In SQLite I think you would use REAL for 32.99. The first paragraph of (https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) is quite interesting about this.

Comment: @user3425506, OP is probably using Postgresql (pgadmin). SQLite does things in its own, more or less data type agnostic way.

Comment: @jarlh I see what you mean: pgadmin presumably stands for Postgres admin. Probably the OP has a good reason for using Postgres but for me SQLite is more than adequate and far less trouble to set up than other SQL implementations which are server based.

Comment: @user3425506, the <sql> tag says "_Answers to questions tagged with SQL should use ISO/IEC standard SQL._" - which is far from SQLite in this case.

Comment: pgAdmin4 uses postgresql yeah, at least i think so. I got it to work now, at least, the table import read everything correctly from what i could tell, so that's a big win for me. Thank you all for all your help!